# Filter Data just show first data detail android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

i've a filter data to search data in customlistview, but this filterable just show the first detail of data, what should i do to fix the problem ? please give me a suggestion....
thank you
this is the source

```
cari_data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_cari_pel);
    cari_data.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            _tampilData.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

        }});
    database = new DB_OpenHelper(this);

    if (!database.checkDatabase()) {
        try{
            database.createDatabase();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            throw new Error ("Unble to create database");
        }
    }
    try{database.openDatabase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
    listTampilData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_pelajaran);
    TampilDataPelajaran(view);

}
    private void TampilDataPelajaran(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dbhelper = new DB_OpenHelper(this);
        datapelajaran = dbhelper.getMainActiviyPel(nama);


            tampilData = new ArrayList<ListBinder_Pelajaran>();
            ListBinder_Pelajaran datpel;
            arrkode = new String[datapelajaran.size()];
            for (int i =0 ; i<datapelajaran.size();i++){
                datpel = new ListBinder_Pelajaran();
                _data = datapelajaran.elementAt(i);
                arrkode[i] = _data.getNama_pel();
                datpel.Nama_pel =_data.getNama_pel();

                tampilData.add(datpel);
            }

            _tampilData = new Adapter_Pelajaran(tampilData, this);
            listTampilData.setAdapter(_tampilData);
            listTampilData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int listId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id));
                    Intent detil = new Intent (TampilPelajaran.this, DetailPelajaran.class);
                    detil.putExtra (namapel, arrkode[listId]);
                    detil.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    detil.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(detil);
                }

            });
}
```

Comment: u need to make your own filter class

Comment: could you tell me more details about it ?